# Spark DropDownList pulldown incorrectly positioned inside SWFLoader

Tags: flash, apache-flex, drop-down-menu, offset, swfloader

Today I encountered this bug:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26147

I am loading another team's application via SWFLoader into my own application.  For various reasons, I ***must*** use the flag loadForCompatibility and set it to true.  I have noticed that ALL the spark DropDownList instances in the loaded sub-application offset their dropdowns incorrectly.  Since my application has a header, the pulldowns are offset vertically by the height of the header.
MX versions of ComboBox in a test sub-application do not have this problem.

I tried adding the line:

-includes=mx.managers.systemClasses.MarshallingSupport

and

-includes+=mx.managers.systemClasses.MarshallingSupport

to my Application's compiler options but it has no effect.

I also noticed, when trying to write an import statement, that MarshallingSupport doesn't even exist.  I am using FlashBuilder 4.  I am using the default SDK (4.1).  The sub-application is the same.

Is there any kind of workaround for this?  Am I doing something wrong?  Why must this be?
Telling the other team to switch all their s:DropDownList to mx:ComboBox is going to be onerous to say the least.  It will also be very time consuming since the APIs are different.  I really hope there is something I can do to solve this problem.  Please tell me I am doing it wrong.

Comment: As a workaround, you might try to create a custom skin for the DropDownLists in which you compensate for the offset.

Comment: The version of Flash Builder you're using here isn't as important as the version of Flex you're using.  Are you also using Flex 4?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com You are referring to the SDK, right?  The SDK is set to 4.1 (default)

Comment: Correct; I Was referring to the SDK...  @RIAStar's suggestion is the best one I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so one option was to make a new DropdownListSkin that modified the behavior of AnchorPopUp.
That was an ok solution.
But it turns out with some more struggling, I got "-includes+=mx.managers.systemClasses.MarshallingSupport" to finally work in the compiler.
I was able to confirm whether marshalling support was on or off by putting a break point at line 1432 of MatrixUtil.getConcatenatedMatrixHelper().  Or, alternatively you can check by calling:

```
 ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition("mx.managers.systemClasses.MarshallingSupport");
```

So if like me you think you have your compiler options set correctly, use the above code to confirm that you really actually honest-to-god have it right.  As long as MatrixUtil can access MarshallingSupport, then your spark pulldowns, etc. will work fine.

Furthermore, I got some help from the Adobe forums:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1034957

edit: I am flagging this as an answer so SO will stop asking me to accept an answer.